# Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to parse a text document using VBA and return the path given in the text file.  For example, the text file would look like:

```
*Blah blah instructions
*Blah blah instructions on line 2
G:\\Folder\...\data.xls
D:\\AnotherFolder\...\moredata.xls
```

I want the VBA to load 1 line at a time, and if it starts with a `*` then move to the next line (similar to that line being commented). For the lines with a file path, I want to write that path to cell, say `A2` for the first path, `B2` for the next, etc.

The main things I was hoping to have answered were:

1. What is the best/simple way to read through a text file using VBA?
2. How can I do that line by line?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

for the most basic read of a text file, use `open`

example:

```
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "Filename" For Input As #FileNum

While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
    ' decide what to do with dataline, 
    ' depending on what processing you need to do for each case
Wend
```

#Author note - Please stop adding in `close #FileNum` - it's addressed in the comments, and it's not needed as an improvement to this answer

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but Line Input has problems with anything other than strictly a CR or CRLF combination (i.e. LF on its own) - FSO has no such problems (but yeah, is probably a little bit slower)

Comment: Remember Close #FileNum at the end!

Comment: For anyone else wondering: `DataLine` excludes the terminating `CR` or `CRLF` ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

Comment: ON ERROR is required.

Comment: @NoChance, not if the file is just as expected, but programming styles were not what the question is about.

Comment: um, from what I understand, it's a really bad idea to leave out the `CLOSE` command.

Comment: depends. all files are closed on exit, but it's much better form to close the files when you expect them to be closed - saves trouble later. As @MagnusSmith mentioned this, I upvoted that comment rather than edit my answer

Answer (score 53):

I find the FileSystemObject with a TxtStream the easiest way to read files

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading, False)
```

Then with this `txtStream` object you have all sorts of tools which intellisense picks up (unlike using the `FreeFile()` method) so there is less guesswork. Plus you don' have to assign a FreeFile and hope it is actually still free since when you assigned it.

You can read a file like:

```
Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    txtStream.ReadLine
Loop
txtStream.Close
```

NOTE: This requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: thanks for the reply Brad. I think this also will accomplish what I wanted just fine

Comment: Actually, without dimensioning `txtStream` as a `TextStream` object, there will be no intellisense

Comment: You can also do this without checking the Microsoft Scripting Runtime box by using `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` instead of `Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject`, you just lose the intellisense

Answer (score 41):

For completeness; working with the data loaded into memory;

```
dim hf As integer: hf = freefile
dim lines() as string, i as long

open "c:\bla\bla.bla" for input as #hf
    lines = Split(input$(LOF(hf), #hf), vbnewline)
close #hf

for i = 0 to ubound(lines)
    debug.? "Line"; i; "="; lines(i)
next
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can do the same in FileSystemObject, but FSO will often fail to run due to security restrictions, and it is significantly slower.

Comment: ... but assumes the file will fit into memory

Answer (score 2):

You Can use this code to read line by line in text file and You could also check about the first character is "*" then you can leave that..

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim ReadData as String

    Open "C:\satheesh\myfile\file.txt" For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1) 
       Line Input #1, ReadData 'Adding Line to read the whole line, not only first 128 positions
    If Not Left(ReadData, 1) = "*" then
       '' you can write the variable ReadData into the database or file
    End If 

    Loop

    Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

The below is my code from reading text file to excel file.

```
Sub openteatfile()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim filepath As String
filepath = "C:\Users\TarunReddyNuthula\Desktop\sample.ctxt"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Al:L20").ClearContents
Open filepath For Input As #1
i = l
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, linefromfile
lineitems = Split(linefromfile, "|")
        For j = LBound(lineitems) To UBound(lineitems)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j + 1).value = lineitems(j)
        Next j
    i = i + 1 
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post as text instead of a image?

Comment: jeffld, I uploaded the string