# Concatenating text files in VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I want to concatenate several text files structured in the exact same way, but I want to keep the first line only for the first file and kill that header line for the consecutive 20+ files.
Thus far, I've been able to concatenate by using the following script, but I don't know how to avoid the first line.

```
Sub snb() 'This Macro opens all .txt files in a given path and concatenates them
    c00 = "C:\some path" ' the path
    c01 = Dir(c00 & "*.txt")
    Location = "destination_path\" 'Here is where the combined file will be

    DateStamp = CStr(Year(Date)) & CStr(Month(Date)) & CStr(Day(Date))


    x = 0

    Do Until c01 = ""

        If x = 0 Then

            c02 = c02 & CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(c00 & c01).readall
            c01 = Dir
            x = 1

        Else

            c02 = c02 & vbCrLf & CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(c00 & c01).readall '
            c01 = Dir

        End If
    Loop

    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").createtextfile(Location & DateStamp & "_new.txt").write c02

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this `VBA` or `vb.net`?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba).  You may be able to use an IF statement and a count variable to determine if you have already used line 1.

Comment: Don't concatenate subsequent files immediately.  Read them into a temporary string.  Search that string for vbCrLf (end of first line) and then concatenate the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your `If` statement should look like :

```
If x = 0 Then

    c02 = c02 & CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(c00 & c01).readall
    c01 = Dir
    x = 1

Else

    fs = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(c00 & c01).readall
    toRemove = InStr(fs, vbCrLf) + 1
    fs = Right(CStr(fs), Len(fs) - toRemove)
    c02 = c02 & vbCrLf & fs
    c01 = Dir

End If
```

What this does is :

1. Extracts entire file content
2. Finds the first "Line Feed" character
3. Creates a string with everything following that "Line Feed"
4. Concatenates that string into the cumulative c02.