# Using Regular expression in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

This is my sample record in a Text format with comma delimited

```
901,BLL,,,BQ,ARCTICA,,,,
```

i need to replace `,,, to ,,`

The Regular expression  that i tried

```
  With regex
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern="^(?=[A-Z]{3})\\,{3,}",",,"))$ -- error
```

Now i want to pass Line from file to Regex to correct the record, can some body guide me to fix this i am very new to VBA

I want to read the file line by line pass it to `Regex`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your original pattern I tried using `.Pattern = "^\d{3},\D{3},,,"` which works on the sample record as with the 3 number characters , 3 letters,,,

In the answer I have used a more generalised pattern `.Pattern = "^\w*,\w*,\w*,,"` This also works on the sample and mathces 3 commas each preceded with 0 or more alphanumeric characters followed directly by a fourth comma. Both patterns require a match to be from the begining of the string.

Pattern `.Pattern = "^\d+,[a-zA-Z]+,\w*,,"` also works on the sample record. It would specify that before the first comma there should be 1 or greater numeric characters (and only numeric characters) and before the second comma ther should be 1 or more letters (and only letters). Before the 3rd comma there could be 0 or more alphanumeric characters.

The left function removes the rightmost character in the match ie. the last comma to generate the string used by the Regex.Replace.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str As String

    str = "901,BLL,,,BQ,ARCTICA,,,,"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print str

    str = strConv(str)
    Debug.Print str
End Sub

Function strConv(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim oMatches As Object
    Dim oMatch As Object

    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^\w*,\w*,\w*,,"
    End With

    Set oMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)
    If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each oMatch In oMatches
            str = objRegEx.Replace(str, Left(oMatch.Value, oMatch.Length - 1))
        Next oMatch
    End If
    strConv = str

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub test()

    Dim str As String
    str = "901,BLL,,,BQ,ARCTICA,,,,"

    str = strConv(str)
    MsgBox str

End Sub

Function strConv(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim objRegEx As Object, allMatches As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = ",,,"
    End With

    strConv = objRegEx.Replace(str, ",,")

End Function
```

Comment: thanks! and how do i pass the entire file ? to read line by line!

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba) which shows how to read text file line by line.

Comment: and the regex replace even last 3 commas with 2 commas,it must only replace after `BLL`