# How to delete a line in a txt file if number exists in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have read this post: [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba). This post tells you how to read a line from a text file. However, I need to read a line and check whether it contains a number and if it does, I need to delete the line and save the text file.

```
While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
    If FindValue(DataLine) Then
        'Stuck here.
    End If
Wend

End Sub

Function FindValue(ByVal DataLine As Variant) As Boolean
    For Index = 0 To NoOfLiquidatedDeals - 1
        pos = InStr(DataLine, NoOfLiquidatedDealsArray(Index))
        If pos > 0 Then
            FindValue = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I can read the line and check whether it contains a number. But I am not sure how to delete the line and save the text file. Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to re-write the file,
In other words:

1. Open `input.txt` for Input
2. Open `output.txt` for Output
3. Write all the lines that don't match to `output.txt`
4. Delete `input.txt`
5. Rename `output.txt` to `input.txt`

And in code:

```
Open "input.txt" For Input as #1
Open "output.txt" For Output as #2
While Not EOF(#1)
    Input #1, DataLine
    If Not FindValue(DataLine) Then
        Print #2,DataLine
    End If
Wend
Close #2
Close #1
Kill "input.txt"
Name "output.txt" As "input.txt"
```