# Copy Entire HTML File Text to a Cell in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an HTML file that I wrote to create a string. The file is called `MyHTMLfile` and it is located in `U:\temp`.

How can I easily (and with as little as possible computing time) copy the entire string from HTML to `Range("IV" & RowCount)`?

Comment: Probably with VBA - what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire file to be put in a single cell...

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Range("IV" & RowCount) = .OpenTextFile("u:\temp\myhtmlfile.htm").ReadAll()
End With
```

This is assuming your `myHtmlFile` has an extension of `.htm`. Change as needed.

Comment: The cell is being filled with nothing. Apparently it is not copying the HTML correctly.

Comment: To test this i filled it with the letter A, and after running the code it was blank. That does mean, however, that it is finding the file and trying to copy from it

Comment: Hmm. Works okay here. Are you sure you're looking in the proper destination cell? Try changing it to `Range("A1") = ...` and see if it appears in `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

How's something like this:

```
Sub test21()
'Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba
Dim FileNum As Integer, i As Integer
Dim DataLine As String

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open "U:\Temp\myHTMLFile.html" For Input As #FileNum
i = 1 ' This is where you want to set your `RowCount`.
While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
    Range("IV" & i).Value = DataLine
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Oddly enough it is not locating the file. I am certain of the naming and the file location, but it simply says that it cannot locate the file... strange

Comment: Yup. I've triple checked that and it isnt locating the file. Drive is correct, folder and spelling are both correct...

Comment: Can you put a copy on a local drive (one on your computer), and see if it works? It might have an issue reading from a network.  One thing to try, is to turn on macro recorder and open the HTML file (or try), then it'll give you the proper context to open. (It should anyways).  Edit: I am able to open from a network drive, with the above code.  Perhaps there are permissions on your `U:\` drive?

Comment: Ill try putting it on the local drive