# Extracting text from string - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to generate X,Y,Z strings from a text file to input into a CAD program like AutoCAD or Inventor.  I would like to do this in Excel using VBA.

The text file contains strings like this:

```
G0X.5384Z.05
G1X.634Z-.0327F.004
Z-.9184F.006
X.592Z-.9548F.004
```

and I would like to extract X, Y, and Z coordinates from that. To be clear, this text has been pasted into Excel and Column A contains each line. Line 1 would come out as "X.5384" in one column and "Z.05" in another.

I know enough VBA to remove the XYZ from the strings but I cannot figure out how to pull a specific portion out.  There is no guarantee that they will be in XYZ order or another letter will not be in the middle of them.

I have read a bit about the Regex.Split and with enough time I could probably get it to split the entire string out but I would like to just pull X, Y, and Z coordinates out and ignore the rest if possible.

Comment: Can you not work off the text file directly?

Comment: I could but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You could start with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put this little User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function GetData(r As Range, CH As String) As String
   Dim v As String, i As Long, j As Long, L As Long, CHm As String

   v = r.Text
   L = Len(v)
   GetData = ""
   i = InStr(1, v, CH)
   If i = 0 Then Exit Function
   GetData = CH

   For j = i + 1 To L
      CHm = Mid(v, j, 1)
      If CHm = "-" Or CHm = "." Or CHm Like "[0-9]" Then
         GetData = GetData & CHm
      Else
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next j
End Function
```

Then in **B1** enter: `=getdata(A1,"X")` and copy down.
In **C1** enter: `=getdata(A1,"Y")` and copy down.
In **D1** enter: `=getdata(A1,"Z")` and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thats an awesome solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this works great for me.  I was able to (probably the wrong way) add a replace code right after GetData = GetData & CHm and pull out X, Y, and Z letters to just leave the coordinates.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternate solution that does not use VBA, use row 1 as a header row and put in the letters you're looking for, as shown in this image:

[image: Sample layout]

In cell B2 is this formula and then copy over and down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2,"*"&B$1&"*")=0,"",MID($A2,SEARCH(B$1,$A2),MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(--(MID($A2&" ",SEARCH(B$1,$A2)+1,ROW($1:$10))&0)),),0)))
```

Comment: Your code worked great as well but I went with the other as it was easier for me to pull out the X, Y, and Z in VBA.  Thanks for your code, I'm still trying to understand it!