# how do we rewrite this program that it collects data from input.txt file with content

Tags: excel, vba

How do we rewrite this program in order for it to collect data from input.txt file or second excel sheet with content:
test
mark
class ...
and delete rows in exel file with this text.

```
Sub RemoveRowsAv()
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
Dim n As Long, d As Long
n = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For d = n To 1 Step -1
  If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(d, 7).Text, "test", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(d, 7).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
  If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(d, 7).Text, "mark", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(d, 7).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next d
End Sub
```

file input.txt

```
test
mark 
class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You read the file and put every word of that file in a collection.
Then, instead of:

```
If InStr(..., "test", ...) Then
  ....EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

You do something like:

```
For Each entry in Collection
  If Instr(..., entry, ...) Then
    ....EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next
```

Comment: how do we connect two program together Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = "C:\test\geographical-coordinates.txt"
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

posLat = InStr(text, "latitude")
posLong = InStr(text, "longitude")
Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, posLat + 10, 5)
Range("A2").Value = Mid(text, posLong + 11, 5)

Answer (score 0):

Test the next code, please. It needs a text file named "input.txt". In my example code it is located in the folder where `ThisWorkbook` has the path:

```
Sub RemoveRowsAv()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, n As Long, d As Long, arrCond, El, txtFileName As String
 Dim objFSO As Object, objTxt As Object, rngDel As range, strText As String

 Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet (not necessary to be activated)
 sh.cells.ClearFormats
 txtFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "input.txt" 'fill here the text file full name
 
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If Not objFSO.FileExists(txtFileName) Then 'check if the text file exists in the path
    MsgBox "The text file does not exist on the path: """ & txtFileName & """."
    Exit Sub
 End If
 Set objTxt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtFileName, 1)
    strText = objTxt.ReadAll      'read the text file content
 objTxt.Close

 arrCond = Split(strText, vbCrLf) 'put it in an array splitting on vbCrLf (end of line)

 n = range("G" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of the G:G column
 For d = 1 To n            'iterate between the existing range
    For Each El In arrCond 'check each element of the array keeping conditions
        If El <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, sh.cells(d, 7).text, El, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then 'if the range to be deleted not Set
                    Set rngDel = sh.cells(d, 7)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.cells(d, 7)) 'if already Set
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next El
 Next d
 'delete all the rows at once:
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```