# How can I split what excel reads from a text file rather than reading it all. My text files are too big to read all

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that is reading a text file and parsing various data from it. It's working fine until I get a text file with somewhere a over 5million lines in it. It can read 4.8mil but not 6.8. Rather than reading all the file how can I split what it reads into 2 or more parts? I can't code and I don't really understand VBA, but this is what I have put together and it works nicely on files of 4.8m lines or less.
Is there any way to run the script reading lines 1-4mil then the remainder or with larger files 1-4000000, then 4000001-8000000 and so on? Many thanks

`your text`     Sub Logs1()

```
 Dim fn As String, txt As String, delim As String, a() As String
 Dim i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, n As Long, x, y
 fn = "D:\file that I am reading"    ' ?Change here (File Path)
 delim = vbTab    ' ?Change here (delimiter)

 temp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
 
 x = Split(temp, vbCrLf)
 ReDim a(1 To UBound(x) + 1, 1 To 100)
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(x)
     If InStr(1, x(i), "first search parameter", 1) > 0 Then
          n = n + 1: y = Split(x(i), delim)
         For ii = 0 To UBound(y)
             a(n, ii + 1) = y(ii)
   
              Next
     ElseIf InStr(1, x(i), "second search parameter", 1) > 0 Then
         For ii = 0 To UBound(y)
             n = n + 1: y = Split(x(i + ii), delim)
             For iii = 0 To UBound(y)
                 a(n, iii + 1) = y(iii)
   
              Next
              Next
     ElseIf InStr(1, x(i), "third search parameter", 1) > 0 Then
         For ii = 0 To 1
             n = n + 1: y = Split(x(i + iii), delim)
             For iiii = 0 To UBound(y)
                 a(n, iiii + 1) = y(iiii)
   
             Next
             Next
     ElseIf InStr(1, x(i), "fourth search parameter", 1) > 0 Then
         For ii = 0 To UBound(y)
             n = n + 1: y = Split(x(i + iiiii), delim)
             For iiiii = 0 To UBound(y)
                 a(n, iiiii + 1) = y(iiiii)
                             
             Next
             Next
     ElseIf InStr(1, x(i), "fifth search parameter", 1) > 0 Then
         For ii = 0 To UBound(y)
             n = n + 1: y = Split(x(i + iiiiii), delim)
             For iiiiii = 0 To UBound(y)
                 a(n, iiiiii + 1) = y(iiiiii)
     Next
     Next
 
     End If
 Next 
 If n > 0 Then
     Sheets(8).Cells(2, 1).Resize(n, 1).Value = a
 End If
 ''End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba)

Comment: What happens when you have the larger file? (eg Error message and, if so, what; freezing; computer explodes; something else). Do you have 32-bit or 64-bit Office?

Comment: `Sheets(8).Cells(2, 1).Resize(n, 1).Value` Why are you saving only 1 column of the array ?

Comment: Hi, the method that CLR suggests doesn't work for what I am wanting. Sorry

Comment: What happens with the larger files is that I just get an error message. I checked this with a larger file by cutting it down in size by eliminating 2mil lines or so and it worked again although missing some of the data I was looking for.

Comment: CDP1802, I only want a single column because that is how the data is coming, no comma separation etc. just a single line of comments that just goes into a single cell. From there I'm separating the data and time ordering it.

Comment: And can you answer my other questions also? **What is the error message?  What line does it occur on? Do you have 32-bit or 64-bit Office?**